# When using execute command in geany, blank terminal appears

Tags: python, geany

I'm using Python 2.7 with Geany on Windows 10. Whenever I click the 'execute' button a blank terminal appears, with no result.

I think that this has nothing to do with the code as when I even try to do a simple 'hello world' program the same thing happens.

Could someone please tell me why a blank terminal appears instead of the programme I'm trying to run? It frustrates me greatly.

Please inform me about how to fix this.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but this looks like several statements. For others to help you, they need to know (amongst other things) what your actual question is :-)

Comment: This window is started by Geany to execute your code. Please check manual for details https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#terminal-vte-preferences

Comment: Hi Neill sorry if I was unclear, I have edited my question. Hope it helps :)

Comment: If you're referring to the embedded terminal, the wiki page "Running Geany on Windows" at https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/win32/running indicates that the embedded terminal emulation feature is missing from the Windows build of Geany.